# How to write regular expression in powershell

Tags: regex, string, powershell, powershell-3.0

I need regular expression in powershell to split string by a string **##** and remove string up-to another character (**;**).

I have the following string.

```
$temp = "admin@test.com## deliver, expand;user1@test.com## deliver, expand;group1@test.com## deliver, expand;"
```

Now, I want to split this string and get only email ids into new array object. my expected output should be like this.

```
admin@test.com
user1@test.com
group1@test.com
```

To get above output, I need to split string by the character **##** and remove sub string up-to semi-colon (**;**).

Can anyone help me to write regex query to achieve this need in powershell?.

Comment: You could use `[regex]::Split($temp, '##[^;]*;')`, too, but you'd need to remove leading/trailing `'##[^;]*;'` to get rid of empty values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use regex-based splitting with your approach, you can use `##[^;]*;` regex and this code that will also remove all the empty values (with `| ? { $_ }`):

```
$res = [regex]::Split($temp, '##[^;]*;') | ? { $_ }
```

The `##[^;]*;` matches:

- `##` - double `#`
- `[^;]*`  - zero or more characters other than `;`
- `;` - a literal `;`.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%23%23%5b%5e%3b%5d*%3b&i=admin%40test.com%23%23+deliver%2c+expand%3buser1%40test.com%23%23+deliver%2c+expand%3bgroup1%40test.com%23%23+deliver%2c+expand%3b)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use [[regex]::Matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx) to get all occurrences of your regular expression. You probably don't need to split your string first if this suits for you:

```
\b\w+@[^#]*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/R378IBrF8en6LUbQ)

**PowerShell code:**

```
[regex]::Matches($temp, '\b\w+@[^#]*') | ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[0].Value }
```

**Output:**

```
admin@test.com
user1@test.com
group1@test.com
```